# url automatically redirect to my magento2 site

Tags: magento2, url, redirect

When user type url "xyz" that will automatically  redirect to my magento2 website "https://mywebsite". How can I achieve this in magento2? Please help me to do this.

Comment: Use .htaccess to redirect

Comment: Donot understood and when you want to redirect?